# ERROR: Cannot read property 'userLocation' of null or service is null

Tags: angular, typescript

I have gone through different threads on SO regarding null service. But I didn't get my answers. What I am trying to do is when my component is being loaded, I am trying to get the user's current location.

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private userLocation: UserLocationService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getLocation()
    }

    getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }

    showPosition(position) {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude)
        let userCordinates = {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
        this.userLocation.setCurrentUserLocation(userCordinates)
    }
}
```

Once I get the coordinates, I am trying to set the coodinates in a service, so that I can get it from another component. This is the service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserLocationInterface } from './user.location.interface'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserLocationService {

  constructor() { }

  userLocation: UserLocationInterface
    getCurrentUserLocation() {
        return this.userLocation;
    }

    setCurrentUserLocation(userLocationCords) {
        this.userLocation = userLocationCords;
    }
}
```

I have mentioned the service in app.module in providers container. I can see the coordinates in console logs. But when my main component is being loaded, I can see this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'userLocation' of null
```

This `userLocation` is throwing this error in main component. I didn't get here what's wrong. Is my service null ? Or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: produce stackblitz ?

Comment: If you have only one module, you could remove the `{providedIn: 'root'}` option in the `@Injectable()` decorator.

Comment: your ```this``` is pointing to nothing, you can check whether your component is rendering without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way that you bound the `getCurrentPosition` callback, `this` does not refer to anything in that callback.

Try using the arrow function so that the current context refers to your component

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => this.showPosition(pos));
```